# jQuery datatables - fnGetHiddenNodes() example

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatables plug-in on my HTML Table.

I wanted to know how do I go about using the fnGetHiddenNodes() function to extract a particular row from my table.

More specifically, 
I've this as one of the columns

`tr

td align="center"

input type="checkbox" id="caseConsent(index)" name="caseConsent"

input type="hidden" id="protCaseInst(index)" name="protCaseInst" value="some value here..unique to each row"

td`

td.../td

/tr

And currently the way, I'm extracting values from this table is as follows:
(Basically, push the value of hidden field 'protCaseInst' of each row that is checked into protCaseInstArray)

`$("#mydiv-element").find("input[type='checkbox' name='caseConsent']:checked ~ input[name='protCaseInst']").each(function() {
         protCaseInstArray.push($(this).val());
  });`

Using this code though, if I select rows from 2nd page of my datatable, they don't appear in my protCaseInstArray.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I already have the answer. I tried

$(oTable.fnGetNodes()).find("input[@type=checkbox @name=caseConsent]:checked ~ input[name='protCaseInst']").each(function() { protCaseInstArray.push($(this).val()); });

And it seems to work!